# A question about non-singular matrix size $n×n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Matrix $A$ is a matrix of size $n×n$ with entries of even and odd natural numbers that differ from one another. In order for $A$ to be a non-singular matrix, the minimum number of odd number entries is · ·

GIve me a hint.
We know non singular matrix is a matrix that have determinat is equal 0.

Comment: Hint: Can you think of any particular nonsingular $n \times n$ matrix?

Comment: @JohnHughes i don't understand what did you mean..

Comment: give me other hint please

Comment: To be honest, I misread "that differ from one another." Others take it to mean "all different" (which seems right), while I took it to mean "not all the same" (which seemed like a weird condition, because it's already implied by "nonsingular").

Comment: *"We know non singular matrix is a matrix that have determinat is equal 0."* I thought the opposite, i.e. that a singular square matrix has determinant $0$  and a non-singular square matrix has a non-zero determinant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily construct a nonsingular matrix with distinct even positive integer entries. It is enough to make the diagonal elements larger than the sum of the other elements in the corresponding row.

Comment: Do you have a theorem about that?

Comment: and how to apply that to the problem?

Comment: It is the Gershgorin circle theorem (you can look it up at wikipedia, for example). In our situation, start with the numbers $2,4,6,\cdots$ and make the diagonal larger than the sum. Than continue with the next even numbers in the second row, make the diagonal element larger than the sum and so on.

Comment: that theorem about eigenvalues..

Comment: Yes, in particular it guarantees that eigenvalue $\ 0\ $ is impossible , if we construct the matrix like described.

Comment: Do you have simple answer?

Comment: You mean avoiding the "big guns" ? No, I have no easier approach in mind.

Comment: @Peter One may think of using the Vandermonde matrix in which every line is suitably multiplied by $\alpha_j$. For example:$\begin{pmatrix}&2&\dots&2^n\\&4^n&\dots&4^{2n}\\&\vdots&\ &\vdots\\ &{2^n}^n&\dots&{2^n}^{2n}\end{pmatrix}$